# How to modify a global variable in a method

Tags: java, android

I have an animation for android with 10 buttons, and I need to trigger this buttons with an order, so I have a variable named order, if order=1 button1 can get activated, if order=2 button 2 can get activated and so on. When I open the program, an animation starts, then a second animation repeats itself after the first one ends and in between I need to change the variable order to 1. I have the next code:

```
public class Juego extends Activity
{
    private AnimationDrawable animacion, loop;
    private MediaPlayer miPlayer;
    private int order = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);
    ImageView video = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secuencia);
    video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_drawable_start);
    animacion = (AnimationDrawable) video.getBackground();
    animacion.start();
    checkIfAnimationDone0(animacion);
}
public void checkIfAnimationDone0(AnimationDrawable anim)
{
    final AnimationDrawable a = anim;
    int timeBetweenChecks = 20;
    android.os.Handler h = new android.os.Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (a.getCurrent() != a.getFrame(a.getNumberOfFrames() - 1))
            {
                checkIfAnimationDone1(a);
            }
            else
            {
                ImageView video = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secuencia);
                video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_drawable_loop_inicio);
                loop = (AnimationDrawable) video.getBackground();
                loop.start();
                order=1;
            }
        }
    }, timeBetweenChecks);
};

public void onClickButton2(View any)
{
    if (order == 1)
    {
        ImageView video = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secuencia);
        video.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_drawable_boton_1);
        animacion = (AnimationDrawable) video.getBackground();
        miPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Juego.this, R.raw.sonido_boton_1);
        animacion.start();
        miPlayer.start();
        checkIfAnimationDone1(animacion);
        order=2;
    }
}
```

etc..

The problem is that the value of the global variable order does not get changed in the line order=1, and the method onClickButton() cannot start. How do I solve this?

Comment: `order` is NOT a global variable; it is an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In checkIfAnimationDone0(), when

```
a.getCurrent() != a.getFrame(a.getNumberOfFrames() - 1)
```

you go to checkIfAnimationDone1(), so order is never set as 1.

Change checkIfAnimationDone1() in checkIfAnimationDone0() to checkIfAnimationDone0().